# Group items by month in backbone collection view?

Tags: collections, backbone.js

I have a simple collection of documents in my backbone app. This collection has a view that contains all the documents and they should be grouped by the month they were created in.

This view has to update in real-time - when I create a new document or modify an existing one, it should be added/moved to correct place in the view.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a [comparator](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-sort) method for your collection (using groupBy, as suggested by the previous answer, or any other method that suits your needs).  Then, you should have your collection trigger the render method everytime there's an "add", "remove" or "reset" event triggered so that the view is updated in "real-time".

for example, in your views initialize method, one way to do it would be:

```
  collection.documents.on "add", @render
  collection.documents.on "remove", @render
  collection.documents.on "reset", @render
```

the purpose of the comparator method is precisely to keep collection elements sorted at all time.

Comment: That seems to work, now I just need to figure out how to: 1) keep the documents inside the groups ordered by date (most recent first) 2) keep the months ordered by most recent first

Comment: Depends very much on how you organized your data. Simplest way would be to do it "manually" inside the render method: do the sorting with one of backbone and/or underscore's built-in methods then render the sorted items. Or if you want to be fancy, your collection could have nested sub-collections (for the months) that would have their own comparator methods; you would then have to render each month individually.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone collections has a bunch of methods, including [groupBy](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy). This could be used to group your collection.

The view have to listen to `reset` event of collection, so if the collection reset (mean, it's grouped and update), view have to update the DOM accordingly. The simplest solution, just full re-render of view. You can do some optimizations, if needed,